# DoCmd.Open Does not load my onload criteria in Acces 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am opening a form in VBA with the command DoCmd.OpenForm, but when the form opens it is not loading my onload criteria.
When I open the form in any different way it does load the onload criteria set in VBA.
What am I doing wrong?

I open the form with:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOrder", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
```

And when the form opens it needs to do the following on On Load:

```vb
If Me.POOrderFreeEntry = True Then
    Me.frmOrderDetails.visible = True
    Me.frmOrderDetailsFreeEntry.visible = True
    Me.frmOrderDetailsLarge.visible = False
    Me.frmOrderDetails.Requery
Else
    Me.frmOrderDetails.visible = False
    Me.frmOrderDetailsFreeEntry.visible = False
    Me.frmOrderDetailsLarge.visible = True
    Me.frmOrderDetailsLarge.Requery
End If
```

However it only works if I open the form with a Macro or any other way.
With the DoCmd.OpenForm it is not using the Criteria

Comment: Without seeing the code we are all going to be guessing. Post up the whole routine that is not working, not just the openform line.

Comment: You have no criteria in the open form command. Have a read here http://www.baldyweb.com/wherecondition.htm

Comment: I have tried with the criteria and it gets the same result :-(

Comment: I actually removed it to see if it had any effect.. but with no results

Comment: Okay - so back to my first point, what is the criteria you are trying to set? 
And what other code are you running on load. Please show us the whole code - snippets without context mean nothing.

Comment: The criteria are there.. But I solved it by building the form from scratch again.. and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing isn't criteria to filter a forms content, it is what would go into the current and / or load event, to enable certain controls.

You can simplify your code to;

```
Me.frmOrderDetails.visible = Me.POOrderFreeEntry 
Me.frmOrderDetailsFreeEntry.visible = Me.POOrderFreeEntry 
Me.frmOrderDetailsLarge.visible =  Not Me.POOrderFreeEntry 
Me.frmOrderDetails.Requery
```